# Laptop screen blurry to eye but not in screenshot

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, dpi

I've had my laptop for about a year now. About an hour ago, all the UI went blurry. It seems to only affect certain things,

This webpage appears fine, and images, like the one below of a program on my laptop, look fine:
[image]

However, the actual program (and not the screenshot) appears very, very blurry to my eye. Also, while the webpage and all text on it appears fine, the right-click context menu appears very blurry. Ive even asked other people to compare the screenshot with the actual program and instantly you can tell the difference.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix this? I've tried the Windows 10 DPI fix program and tried changing the compatibility settings to disable scaling on high dpi settings, but neither have worked.

Comment: Maybe you need glasses :)

Comment: Is it in Native Resolution?  Do you know how to adjust Cleartext? (search) is it overcast fuzzy or just blurred pixels?

Comment: Have you checked with external display?